# What's the difference between ExternalSorter and ExternalAppendOnlyMap in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading Spark's source code, I find in its shuffle implementation, during shuffle reading, when `BlockStoreShuffleReader.read` is called, it will firstly use a `ExternalAppendOnlyMap` to aggregate

```
def combineValuesByKey(
    iter: Iterator[_ <: Product2[K, V]],
    context: TaskContext): Iterator[(K, C)] = {
  val combiners = new ExternalAppendOnlyMap[K, V, C](createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiners)
  combiners.insertAll(iter)
  updateMetrics(context, combiners)
  combiners.iterator
}
```

then, it will use a `ExternalSorter` to sort and aggregate. So there will be lots of disk spill/read work here.

```
val resultIter = dep.keyOrdering match {
  case Some(keyOrd: Ordering[K]) =>
    // Create an ExternalSorter to sort the data.
    val sorter =
      new ExternalSorter[K, C, C](context, ordering = Some(keyOrd), serializer = dep.serializer)
...
```

My question is why we need both `ExternalSorter` and `ExternalAppendOnlyMap`? Is it possible we combine these two into one?

I mean their codes look quite similar, why can't we all use `ExternalSorter` rather then `ExternalAppendOnlyMap`? Since it can both aggregate and sort?

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER** I'm only now exploring this part of Spark Core so my understanding may be entirely incorrect.

---

My understanding is that `ExternalAppendOnlyMap` is simply a spillable size-tracking append-only map while `ExternalSorter` can be a buffer or a map (based on map-side combine flag for map-side partial values).

> Is it possible we combine these two into one?

With that I think that they share quite a lot, and `ExternalSorter` seems more flexible (as it can do what ExternalAppendOnlyMap does).

I think the answer to your question is "Yes", but very few people are brave or encouraged enough to implement the changes.